# Beginner hashing & salting

Tags: c#, hash, md5

So I'm rather new to programming (C#) and especially cryptography in general. I tried learning some by copying a couple of functions using the MD5 hashing algorithm and learning how it works. I then connected to a database and made a log in and reset password feature. However, the problem appeared when i tried making the same password, i realised the hashing value would turn out the same regardless of me adding a randomly generated salt into the hash value.

```
    string MD5(string input)
    {
        MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();                                  
        byte[] bytes = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(input));          
        string result = BitConverter.ToString(bytes).Replace("-", String.Empty); 
        return result.ToLower();
    }
    public static byte[] GenerateSalt()
    {
        RNGCryptoServiceProvider saltGenerator = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] salt = new byte[24];
        saltGenerator.GetBytes(salt);
        return salt;
    }
```

So this are my functions for generating salt and hashing an input string. This is the code for resetting passwords by filling out two textboxes in WinForms.

```
        private void HashNewPassword(out byte[] salt, out string hashedPassword)
    {
        string tempHash;
        salt = null;
        hashedPassword = null;

        if (txtPassword1.Text == txtPassword2.Text)
        {
            tempHash = txtPassword1.Text;
            salt = GenerateSalt();
            hashedPassword = MD5(MD5(tempHash + salt));
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception();
        }
    }
```

Lastly, the click-even function:

```
        private void btnFinished_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string hashedPassword;
            byte[] salt;

            HashNewPassword(out salt, out hashedPassword);
            AddPasswordToDB(salt, hashedPassword);
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(error.Message + "   :   " + error.GetType().ToString());
        }
    }
```

As you can see below, the hash value is the same, but the salt differs. Am I adding the salt in a way I should not?

```
bec78d2acfd2eb4f5d7da2fd231bad1c     0x21B5F48096E31092FCCD20EE22EF9B3C307ADDC1C31B8D84          
bec78d2acfd2eb4f5d7da2fd231bad1c     0xC063774EBBD4FAED268811C84D70662F4DDB53BCA52A6720
```

Is there a logical explanation to this, or is there something wrong with the code?
Also, I am not familiar with hashing algorithms, just something I stumbled across and wanted to learn more about. Is there an easier way of doing this? I have read about other algorithms that seems easy enough to use, but as I stated, I am not familiar with this. Security differences between hash algorithms is irrelevant. I did read MD5 was old and not *that secure*, however it's more than enough for my use.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On the line `hashedPassword = MD5(MD5(tempHash + salt))`, you're concatenating a string with an array of bytes. You should either convert the salt into a string, or better yet: pass bytes to `MD5()`.

Comment: I see. What exactly do you mean by "pass bytes to MD5()"?

Comment: You already have to convert the string you pass to your `MD5()` function into a byte array (line 3). If your `MD5` function simply accepted a byte array, then you could get the bytes of the password, concatenate with the bytes of the salt, and then give that resulting byte array to `MD5()`.

Comment: Oh, that's actually brilliant. Why didn't I think of that. Would it be possible converting the hashed password with the salt back to string after adding the salt?

Comment: Sure, you can always go to a string from a byte array via `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes)` (substitute `UTF8` for whatever text encoding you are using).

Comment: Excellent! Thanks!

Comment: You also might get some benefit from using `Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)` which lets you get a valid string that you don't have to replace characters on.

Comment: I wasn't aware. That's convenient. I'll try it out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without going into *security aspects*, I believe you're getting the same hashes, because you are not concatenating the salt as a string: `tempHash + salt`

`salt` is a byte array and by using `+` with a `string`, it's `ToString()` method is called prior to the concatenation. This will **not** result in a string with the actual value.

Try converting the array to an actual string:

`System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(salt)`

A small example to clarify the behavior a little further:

```
byte[] salt = new byte[] {67,79,79,76};
Console.WriteLine(salt.ToString()); // prints System.Byte[]

string saltAsString = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(salt);
Console.WriteLine(saltAsString); // prints COOL
```

Comment: That makes sense. However I got issues with extracting the salt from my database as a string, comparing it to the hashed password written in the textbox. Well, converting it back to `byte[]`rather. Which is why I store it as `varbinary` in SQL. How would I go about solving this?

Comment: Well, I don't know your implementation off course, but it seems like you _are_ storing the actual salt. But since your hash was never created with that salt, you'll never get a match.

Comment: Yeah I get what you mean now, that example helped a lot. Appreciate it!